# sftp get - but exclude node_modules

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, sftp

So my windows computer crashed - and I had to move OS so i moved all my nodejs apps to my web server. Now that I am running ubuntu 20.4 I am needing to get all these folders and copy them to my computer.

I am currently using sftp to do this with the get command, however because these folders have node_module in them it is downloading that directory as well.

Is there away to exclude that directory without deleting it from the server?

Ideally in the long term I'll use rsync but this will be to sync to the server and local.

Comment: Unfortunately, `sftp` doesn't support excluding files - you will probably have to go straight to `rsync` (or `sftp get` only what you really want).